# scope in javascript and execution steps

Tags: javascript, scope

```
(function() {
            var a = 'g';
            function foo() {
                console.log(a);
                a = 7; //
            }
            console.log(foo(), a);
    }());
```

Can anybody explain the step by step execution and out put of this code sample. I got the out put as 'g undefined 7'

Comment: Yes, the step debugger.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can be obtained using a debugger

Comment: you aren't returning anything from your function `foo` which is why `console.log(foo())` returns undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous function and executing right away ([IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression))

Then, in this scope function :

- You declare an `a` var with value `g`
- You declare a function named foo which has visibility on parent function scope (IIFE scope). So it can see the `a` var.
  This `foo`function is not called right away.
- In `log`statement, `foo` is executed :

  - `a` is logged (value `g`)
  - `a` var in IIFE scope is changed to value `7`
  - `foo` returns nothing
- Is then logged :

  - `foo` returns value which is `undefined` (no return value)
  - `a` value, which is `7` after `foo` is executed.

So you have in your console :

```
g
undefined 7
```

Comment: Without IIFE also I am getting the same result. OK I understood foo() will result "undefined" since there is no return statement.But how come 'g' value is accessible to within foo() function. If I add 'var' to 'a' in inside the foo () result will become "undefined undefined g". That means without var keyword  variable 'a' will become global.

Comment: In `foo`, without `var`, `a`is coming from you parent scope (IIFE scope).

If you add `var` to `a` in `foo` function, you "override" the `a`variable coming from parent scope (IIFE function), it is called "shadowing".
The `a` var declared that way in `foo` function is only accessible in `foo` function (and would be accessible in hypothetical sub-functions of `foo`)

Comment: I suggest you to read this good online book : 
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS . The chapter corresponding to your question is in book 2, chapter 3 : https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch3.md

Comment: OK Thanks for your suggestion. I am reading a blog 'Advanced JavaScript Fundamentals'-Lan Hill . While reading I tried to understand the concept by writing small functions with all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ananymous self-invoked function wich is executed automatically without any call.

And the results/steps of execution are:

- `g` is thrown with `console.log(a);`, because initially we have `a="g"`.
- `undefined 7` is thrown with  `console.log(foo(), a);`:

  1. `foo()` will return `undefined` because there's no `return`
     statement
  2. and `a` will return `7`, because we did `a=7`;

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    ...
    ...
}());
```

this is just a way to declare an anonymous function and call it

```
var a = 'g';
function foo() {
     console.log(a);
     a = 7; //
}
console.log(foo(), a);
```

here u are declaring a variable a = 'g' in javascript if u declare a variable using the keyword "var" the scope of that variable si the function, that means that inside that function (also in sub function) everyone can use it.

then u are declaring a foo function, the foo function can see the variable a because foo is declared inside the previous function.
console.log(a) just print the value of a so it will print 'g' and then change the value of a to 7.

after the declaration u call console.log(foo(), a), this means that u are executing foo and printing the return value of foo that is 'undefined' because there is no return statement, and then printing the value of a that after the execution of foo is become 7.

so the output is:

```
g
undefined 7
```